# ¿Como utilizar IF o CASE en una metrica en DAX?

Tags: sql-server

actualmente tengo dos metricas para calcular un promedio. La primera es la manera convecional, ya que el promedio se calcula /10.

```
[Measures].[Puntuacion] / [Measures].[Recuento Fact Calidad Tickets]
```

Pero existe una excepción para un cliente y es que solo para este debe calcularse /8

```
([Measures].[Puntuacion] * 10 / 8) / [Measures].[Recuento Fact Calidad Tickets]
```

Lo que se me ocurre es generar un IF que indique que para cuando la dimensión sea tal haga un calculo y para cuando sea diferente haga otro calculo distinto. Lo que no se es como utilizar el IF en MDX.

Answer (score -1):

Lo normal es hacerlo configurable, así cualquier otro cliente podría tener otra configuración. En la tabla "clientes" creas un campo "metrica". a todos los clientes le guardas 10 y a este cliente especial le guardas un 8.

Luego lo resuelves con una subconsulta:

```
 ([Measures].[Puntuacion] * (select metrica from clientes where id_cliente = X)) / [Measures].[Recuento Fact Calidad Tickets]
```

Esto asumiendo que ya tengas una tabla "clientes".

En caso de que no lo quieras hacer configurable simplemente:
([Measures].[Puntuacion] * (CASE WHEN CLIENTE = 'X' THEN 8 ELSE 10 END)) / [Measures].[Recuento Fact Calidad Tickets]